# Error while running threw installed application using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit

I am trying to check all installed Application and trying to uninstall the one application. But when I am running foreach loop I am getting exception

My code is something like this:

```
int a = 0;
foreach (ManagementObject moobject in mos.Get()) {
    
    if(moobject["Name"].ToString() == "Pos")
    {
        testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Program Names-> " + moobject["Name"].ToString() + " " + a);
    }                
    a++;
}
```

Having Error into the method like this.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Can someone explain why this is happening. I have checked some solution but it does not help exactly. I have tried comparing null values if it is there but it does not help.

Comment: Probably `mos` in `foreach (ManagementObject moobject in mos.Get())` is null

Comment: Yeah That is correct I did try this thing `moobject["Name"].ToString() != null` But it does not catch null one and ignore

Comment: `if (moobject["Name"] != null) ` this worked

Comment: I don't think a .ToString() ever returns null, but it must be called on a non-null instance - that's where your code failed